# ContextMenuStrip item created under DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler contains data from previous click

Tags: c#, datagridview, contextmenustrip

trying to solve this and stuck a bit.

in Form1.Designer.cs I add event:

```
this.dataGridView1.CellMouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(this.DataGridView1_CellMouseUp);
```

Then I use following in Form1.cs:

```
    private void DataGridView1_CellMouseUp(Object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ContextMenuStrip cm = new ContextMenuStrip();
            cm.Items.Add("Data:" + e.RowIndex + e.ColumnIndex);
            ContextMenuStrip = cm;
        }
    }
```

First right click does not show Menu at all, but then next right clicks show data from PREVIOUS clicked cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing the showing of the menu strip:

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
  ContextMenuStrip cm = new ContextMenuStrip();
  cm.Items.Add("Data:" + e.RowIndex + e.ColumnIndex);
  cm.Show(MousePosition);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it works now with following code (thanks for suggestions):

```
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        ContextMenuStrip cm = new ContextMenuStrip();
        cm.Items.Add("Data:" + e.RowIndex + e.ColumnIndex);
        cm.Show(MousePosition);
    }
```

Comment: Isn't that what I answered?

Comment: Weirdly it was not working until I removed "dataGridView1.ContextMenuStrip = cm" line and... could you correct your answer with one I pasted after checking and I will delete mine? Thanks